# Model Binding with checkboxes for filters

Tags: angularjs

I have some checkboxes for a live filter. When i check a filter, the post will be done successfully, but after unchecking the boxes nothing happens. The model keep holding his old value. Can someone help me out with this?

```
{% for filter in musicFilters %}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <label for="" class="control-label col-sm-9">Tes</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="checkbox" name="music[]" ng-model="music.filter_{{ loop.index0 }}" ng-false-value="" ng-true-value="{{ filter.id }}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this package: http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

It works fast and great, no hard time with configuring it :)